# Gluon Application won't run on Mobile

Tags: javafxports

I've downloaded the sample apps for gluon and built them. They run just fine on desktop, but when I launch them on my android phone, i get the "Unfortunately xxx app has stopped" message. Same thing happens with Jose Pereda's [HelloCharm](https://github.com/jperedadnr/HelloCharm).

This is what I get from android emulator logcat from HelloCharm:

```
Logcat
16:45:09.000    1120    org.jpereda.charm   ERROR   AndroidRuntime FATAL EXCEPTION: main
16:45:09.000    1120    org.jpereda.charm   ERROR   AndroidRuntime  Process: org.jpereda.charm, PID: 1120
16:45:09.000    1120    org.jpereda.charm   ERROR   AndroidRuntime  java.lang.RuntimeException: Did not create correct launcher.
16:45:09.000    1120    org.jpereda.charm   ERROR   AndroidRuntime at javafxports.android.FXDalvikEntity.getLauncherAndLaunchApplication(FXDalvikEntity.java:122)
16:45:09.000    1120    org.jpereda.charm   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at javafxports.android.FXDalvikEntity.surfaceCreated(FXDalvikEntity.java:145)
16:45:09.000    1120    org.jpereda.charm   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:572)
16:45:09.000    1120    org.jpereda.charm   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:86)
16:45:09.000    1120    org.jpereda.charm   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:175)
16:45:09.000    1120    org.jpereda.charm   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:847)
16:45:09.000    1120    org.jpereda.charm   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1871)
16:45:09.000    1120    org.jpereda.charm   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
16:45:09.000    1120    org.jpereda.charm   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
16:45:09.000    1120    org.jpereda.charm   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
16:45:09.000    1120    org.jpereda.charm   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
16:45:09.000    1120    org.jpereda.charm   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
16:45:09.000    1120    org.jpereda.charm   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
16:45:09.000    1120    org.jpereda.charm   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
16:45:09.000    1120    org.jpereda.charm   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
16:45:09.000    1120    org.jpereda.charm   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
16:45:09.000    1120    org.jpereda.charm   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
16:45:09.000    1120    org.jpereda.charm   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
16:45:09.000    1120    org.jpereda.charm   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
16:45:09.000    1120    org.jpereda.charm   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
16:45:09.000    1120    org.jpereda.charm   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
16:45:09.000    1120    org.jpereda.charm   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
16:45:09.000    1120    org.jpereda.charm   ERROR   AndroidRuntime  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to init method handles
16:45:09.000    1120    org.jpereda.charm   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at javafxports.android.DalvikLauncher.launchApp(DalvikLauncher.java:160)
16:45:09.000    1120    org.jpereda.charm   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at javafxports.android.FXDalvikEntity.getLauncherAndLaunchApplication(FXDalvikEntity.java:119)
16:45:09.000    1120    org.jpereda.charm   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      ... 21 more
16:45:09.000    1120    org.jpereda.charm   ERROR   AndroidRuntime  Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: createEglSurface []
16:45:09.000    1120    org.jpereda.charm   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:472)
16:45:09.000    1120    org.jpereda.charm   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:857)
16:45:09.000    1120    org.jpereda.charm   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at javafxports.android.DalvikLauncher.initMethodHandles(DalvikLauncher.java:229)
16:45:09.000    1120    org.jpereda.charm   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at javafxports.android.DalvikLauncher.launchApp(DalvikLauncher.java:158)
16:45:09.000    1120    org.jpereda.charm   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      ... 22 more
```

I can't figure out how to resolve this.

Build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.0.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/'
    }
    maven {
        url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/'
    }
}

ext.GLUON_VERSION = "0.0.3"

dependencies {
    compile "com.gluonhq:charm:$GLUON_VERSION"
    desktopRuntime "com.gluonhq:charm-desktop:$GLUON_VERSION"
    androidRuntime "com.gluonhq:charm-android:$GLUON_VERSION"
    iosRuntime "com.gluonhq:charm-ios:$GLUON_VERSION"
}

mainClassName = 'org.jpereda.charm.HelloCharm'

jfxmobile {
    ios {
        forceLinkClasses = [ 'org.jpereda.charm.**.*', 'com.gluonhq.charm.down.**.*' ]
    }
    android{
        androidSdk = '/home/harvey/Documents/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140321/sdk/'
        dalvikSdk = '/home/harvey/Documents/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140321/dalvik-sdk'
        compileSdkVersion = 19
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, post your `build.gradle` file. Note the one on the HelloCharm repo is quite outdated. If you have followed recent samples, you should have a more updated version.

Comment: I edited my question to include the build.gradle file

Comment: Plugin can be updated to 1.0.6, and charm to 1.0.0. DalvikSdk is managed by the plugin. Don't set it. Try these changes and let me know.

Comment: I changed the settings and it works now. Thanks.